# How to render parts of form from ActionListener in JSF

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I have a simple file upload mechanism in one of my jsf pages. Once the file has been uploaded, I have an ActionListener that fires. At this point, I have access to the name of the file that the user uploaded, and I want to add this to an outputText component. How can I re-render the form from java code so that the file is displayed? Can I call some ajax function?

```
/**
 * Called when a file is uploaded
 * @param event The FileUploadEvent that contains info on the file uploaded
 */
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event){ 
    data = event.getFile().getContents();
    name = event.getFile().getFileName();
}
```

Above is the code that runs once the file has been uploaded. You can see I get the name of the file. I need now to re-render the outputText so that the name is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually to be declared in the view side.

Even though you didn't mention anything about it (which is bad; you should always mention in the question which JSF implementation and component libraries exactly you're using and for sure not overgeneralize everything as "standard JSF"), the listener method code which you've there is recognizeable as the one specific to PrimeFaces [`<p:fileUpload>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf).

In that case, you should actually be using component's own `update` attribute which should reference the (relative) client ID of the component you'd like to update on complete of the ajax request.

```html
<p:fileUpload ... update="text" />
...
<h:outputText id="text" value="#{bean.text}" />
```

That's all. You'd in this particular example just have to assign the filename to the `text` property.

#### See also:

- [`<p:fileUpload>` VDL documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/fileUpload.html) — lists all available attribtues.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate it. Ive been reading the Primefaces documentation, but there is so much to get through. If you cant tell, im new to JSF :) so ill be sure to not over generalize my questions. Thanks again.

Comment: Anyway you could assist with this question as well. I have a feeling is has to do with my understanding of how ActionListeners work with regard the the life cycle of JSF. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432767/redirect-from-actionlistener-in-jsf